# android app startup time increase with dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, debugging

I have an issue with my app startup. It increase the "Displayed" Time with adding some dependencies (still not used. just added).
Problem is that whenever I comment these dependencies it reduces the time up to 20ms

Time with dependencies : 1s56ms
Time without dependencies : 1s36ms

Even though i have not used these dependencies. There are no object loaded of these dependencies on memory profiler. So my question is that by just adding dependencies, why it inccreases the "Displayed" time.

Dependencies:

```
   implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.6.0'

   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'

   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'
    def retrofit_version = "2.9.0"

 implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"

 implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
```

Launching Activity Code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var mContext:Context
    lateinit var binding:ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mContext = this
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.btnGo.setOnClickListener {
            Intent(mContext,BasicActivity::class.java).also {
                startActivity(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 20ms is not very much. Those `com.google` dependencies, or transitive dependencies that they pull in, might register a `ContentProvider` and do work there when your process starts.

Comment: Yeah that's 1 or 2 frames, it's unnoticeable to the user. Have you run each version a bunch of times to get an average? That's the kind of time difference that could just be down to what else the device happens to be doing at that specific moment

Comment: My main question is that what if i add other dependencies? If adding single dependency increases such time then it will reach to cold start soon.